# Hard problem about Lipschitz condition. This is a very unusual case.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

Can you please help me with proving Lipschitz condition?

Let: $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $\lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert\leq C\lvert x-y\rvert^\alpha$ for some constants $C\gt 0$, $0\lt\alpha\lt\infty$, and for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

(1) Prove that if $0\lt\alpha\le1$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

(2) Prove that if $1\lt\alpha\lt\infty$, then $f$ is a constant.

Comment: I corrected a few things in the question. Please make sure that I understood your intention correctly.

Comment: Please improve formatting by using $\LaTeX$ and show you efforts. It would be a good idea to remove the begging part from the title, too.

Comment: How did you fix it? I just typed as the syntax it is. But, it did not apply it.

Comment: $\LaTeX$ code must be between dollar signs, as in a $\LaTeX$ document.

Comment: you can see what was added/edited if you click on the last edit.

Comment: @Ludolila Thank you for your revisement. It is my first time to upload my problem. Until so far, I just looked it up concerning what you guys talk. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: Besides the formatting, as @G.Sassatelli pointed out it is good to show you have already given some thought to the problem. I left an answer with some detailed outline of the proof, but in the future make sure you describe your work when asking a question (additionally, and out of curiosity what makes you think your question is "a very unusual case" -- what motivates this statement?)

Comment: @YoungCHOI By the way, for your cultural growth, that hypothesis goes under the name of [Holder condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition), of which the Lipschitz condition is the special case $\alpha=1$.

Comment: Thanks, @HomegrownTomato, I did not know that. I just thought that the OP stumbled upon an exercise asking to prove classical results about Holder-continuous functions without explicitly quoting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the definition of uniform continuity. For any fixed $\varepsilon > 0$, you want to find $\delta=\delta(\varepsilon) > 0$ such that, for *any* $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lvert x-y\rvert \leq \delta$ implies $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert \leq \varepsilon$. Using your hypothesis, why is it sufficient to choose $\delta$ such that $C\delta^\alpha \leq \varepsilon$? (And can you conclude from there?)
2. Prove that $f$ is then differentiable everywhere, by fixing an arbitrary $x$, taking $y=x+h$ and letting $h\to 0$. This will in particular show you that $f^\prime(x)$ not only exists, but equals 0. You will need the assumption $\alpha > 1$ for this, since then $\lvert h\rvert^\alpha = \lvert h\rvert^{1+\beta}$ with $\beta>0$.